# Executing a command after each step in a selenium script?

Tags: python, selenium

I am working with selenium webdriver in python. I have a script:

```
if flag=='e':
    try:
        flag='e1'
        login (user, passwd)
        flag='e2'
        my_script(data)
        flag='e3'
```

I have this set up so that I can find out at what step any failure occurs at. This works fine for a small script, but if it was larger this would be difficult. I wondered if there is a way to execute a python command or block of code after each step in the script. so if the selenium scipt looked like:

```
step A
step B
step C
......
step Z
```

I could set flag = 0 and increment the flag after each step so that the effect is:

```
step A
flag = flag+1
step B
flag = flag+1
step C
flag = flag+1
......
step Z
flag = flag+1
```

Can this be done ? This is more of a general python question than selenium related although I would use it mainly in selenium.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium itself does not provide a facility for this. What you should do is used a proper testing framework to run your tests. They typically have some facility that allows you to run repetitive code before or after each test.

For instance [Behave](https://github.com/behave/behave) has an `after_step` callback that is executed after each step. (It so happens that Behave actually has a notion of "step" in its testing model: a feature contains scenarios which themselves contain steps.)

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting, and good info. For now I want to stick with my selenium scripts the way they are, since I have a large number and don't want to try to convert them to behave scripts. However your idea of using a callback is interesting. Does this problem fall into the category of functional programming or meta-programming in your estimation? I'm pretty new to programming and I've heard the buzzwords but as you can see from my question, I'm not sure how to approach this.

Comment: http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2005/04/20/tracing_python_code.html